# ADF: Cannot make panelLabelAndMessage and selectBooleanCheckbox align with each other in panelGridLayout

Tags: oracle-adf

I have already set the attribute `Valign` of `<af:gridCell>` to middle, but still cannot make them line up horizontally.

The code is like:

```
<af:panelGridLayout>
<af:gridRow>
    <af:gridCell valign="middle">
        <af:panelLabelAndMessage />
    </af:gridCell>
    <af:gridCell valign="middle">
        <af:selectBooleanCheckbox simple="true" readOnly="true" selected="true" />
    </af:gridCell>
</af:gridRow>
</af:panelGridLayout>
```

I also tried valign="strectch", however, when the selectBooleanCheckbox is selected the center of tick remains higher than that of panelLabelAndMessage.

Is there something that I didn't take into consideration?

Answer (score 0):

Use `labelstyle="width:100px"` in your  panelLabelAndMessage   and  selectBooleanCheckbox  use pixel value according to your requirement